# How to write 2 controllers in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Is it possible that spring MVC contain 2 controllers like DispatherServet write more than one time
when we developing spring MVC applications.

Comment: You'll need to make your question more clear

Comment: You want to use multiple controller OR the same controller twice ?

Comment: Do you need multiple Controllers or multiple Dispatcher Servlets?

Comment: @geoand : Really don't know either OP's controller name is Dispatcher Servlets or OP wants Dispatcher Servlets ? Bit confusing ! Question not clear.

Comment: @VaibhavJain Yes I know it is very unclear! Let's see what he'll do with your answer

Comment: @user3451583 : According to question heading I posted the answer. Possible to write 2 different Controllers in Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes..!! It is Possible.
You have to set a `@RequestMapping` annotation at the class level the value of that annotation will be the prefix of all requests coming to that controller.

Example:

For 1st Controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {

}
```

For 2nd Controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("demo")
public class DemoController {

}
```

If both the controller have the same/different methods you can access like this

```
<your server>/test/<RequestMappingName of Method>
<your server>/demo/<RequestMappingName of Method>
```